# Vim command to delete all but selected lines

Tags: vim, line

I would like to do the inverse operation performed by

```
:g/pattern/d
```

i.e Delete all lines in a file which doesn't have `pattern`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `v` to select all line without pattern :
`:v/pattern/d` will achieve what you want to do.

See `:help :v`

Comment: Using this global command seems preferable to shell command because: (1) it's an internal Vim command and doesn't depend on having external grep utility, which could be problem on Windows systems, and (2) unsure about this, but since the shell filter returns essentially an entirely new document, and the global command merely deletes lines, I think the global is preferable for keeping the undo history smaller (and thus faster), and (3) just generally it's good idea to get in habit of using Vim globals (:g and :v) because they let you perform arbitrary action on matching lines, not just delete.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is with a shell filter:

```
:%!grep pattern
```

This command passes your whole file (`%`) to a shell (`!`) which runs it through the `grep pattern` command and returns the output to your editor window.

Comment: With all due to respect, answer provided by Xavier T is the right one. vim provides `:v` for this exact problem.

Comment: I agree. However, the shell filter capability is fantastically useful in its own right.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply negate the pattern

```
:g!/pattern/d
```

This will delete all but the selected lines.