# Is it possible to delete everything except the selected text?

Tags: vim

For example, we have text:

```
<Text>Test_request</Text>
```

Command `vit` will sélect all inside tags, how delete only tags?

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4473793/5587646

Comment: @kmalarski That ignores the selection, *and* it performs whole-line deletion.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *real* real world solution would be to use the `dst` command provided by the ubiquitous [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin.

If you want a vanilla solution:

```
yit"_datP
```

Breakdown:

- `yit` yanks the content of the tag to the default register,
- `"_dat` cuts the whole tag to the "black hole" register,
- `P` puts the content of the default register before the cursor.

See `:help "_`, `:help P`.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement romainl's answer. There is another plugin called [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich) which works similarly to vim-surround. If you have installed vim-sandwich successfully, you can use `sdt` to delete the HTML tag surrounding your text. This works flawlessly for me.